# How to draw circle and write on it

Tags: python, opencv

This is reference image:
[image]

I need to draw circles on it the same way as reference image:
[image]

This is the resultant image:
[image]

This is what the code looks like:

```
img = cv2.imread("foot.png")
cv2.circle(img,(112,71), 4, (0,0,0), -1)
font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
cv2.putText(img, '1', (112,71), font, 1, (84, 29, 108), 1, cv2.LINE_AA)


cv2.imwrite("test.png",img)
```

How do I put number on circle the same way as in reference image? Pixel given in code are for the first position.

Edit: 
I tried this solution on Stackoverflow and it gave this result
[Draw Text inside circle OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55904418/draw-text-inside-circle-opencv)

[image]

Edit 1:
Code:

```
img = cv2.imread("foot.png")

CENTER = (112, 71)

cv2.circle(img, CENTER, 2, (127,0,127), -1)

TEXT_FACE = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_DUPLEX
TEXT_SCALE = 1
TEXT_THICKNESS =1
TEXT = "0"

text_size, _ = cv2.getTextSize(TEXT, TEXT_FACE, TEXT_SCALE, TEXT_THICKNESS)
text_origin = ( int(CENTER[0] - text_size[0] / 2), int(CENTER[1] + text_size[1] / 2))

cv2.putText(img, TEXT, text_origin, TEXT_FACE, TEXT_SCALE, (127,255,127), TEXT_THICKNESS, cv2.LINE_AA)

cv2.imwrite('centertext_out.png', img)
```

Ouput:
[image]

Edit:

This is what I have achieved so far:
[image]

Is there any way to not let circles in second line overlay one another? Is it possible to not let circles cover text?

Comment: there is a function that tells you the place and size of the drawn text. You can use that function to optimize your text size and pos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use different libraries. I think instead of opencv `matplotlib`, `bokeh` or `seaborn` should be better suited for this kind of job. You can do a `scatter plot` with anyone of these and **label your points** with numbers. I assure you it would look a lot better.

As you have requested here is a quick example.
[image]

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img = cv2.imread("your_image_here.png")
```

I used opencv only to read the image. Then specified x and y coordinates pixelwise in an array
. Also the label values as n.

```
x = [120,110,150,367,377,337]
y = [100,200,300,100,200,300]
n = [5.0,4.8,20.5,5.0,4.8,20.5]
```

then I plotted the points on top of the image with desired options such as point size, color, opacity and label size.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 10))

ax.imshow(img)
ax.scatter(x, y, s=200, alpha=0.7, c = "orange")

for i, num in enumerate(n):
    ax.text(x[i], y[i], num, fontsize=12)
```

It is just a short demonstration. You can also define a function to adjust the point colors according to label values or if the points are getting too crowded you can make them smaller dynamically with another function. The point I wanted to make is Opencv is not so practical for a task like yours.
Hope this helped. Good luck. :)

Comment: Can you please share some worthwhile resources or any starting point? Thanks (with regards to tkinter)